# Trying to use LINQ to check if a BitmapSource exists in a List<BitmapSource>

Tags: c#, linq

I need to check if a `BitmapSource` already exists in a `List<BitmapSource>`, but I am not sure what exactly I should compare. The method that will be checking and adding the item to a list gets the `BitmapSource` as a parameter from a routed command from a WPF `UserControl`

I want to do something like this:

```
if(!selectedImages.Any(x => x.SomeBitmapSourceProperty == e.Parameter.SomeBitmapSourceProperty)
     selectedImages.Add(e.Parameter as BitmapSource)
```

What would I use to compare two `BitmapSource` and would I actually be able to access that property from `e.Parameter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from the question, but it seems you want to check using reference equality (i.e. the two `BitmapSource` values point to the same object). You can do this with straight [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx):

```
var candidate = (BitmapSource)e.Parameter;
if(!selectedImages.Contains(candidate))
{
    selectedImages.Add(candidate);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
 if (selectedImages.Count(x =>
         x.SomeBitmapSourceProperty == e.Parameter.SomeBitmapSourceProperty
     ) == 0) selectedImages.Add(e.Parameter as BitmapSource);
```

Comment: You can compare HashCode of this objects. (method `GetHashCode()` )